# How can I get $pagenow equals to the Home Page or specific page on my site?

Tags: conditional-tags, homepage

I'm new to WP and search for some examples on `$pagenow` codes. Everything I saw equals to .php files.

How can I make an if statement that `$pagenow` is equal to my Home Page or specific page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$pagenow` variable is specificly meant to identify pages in the admin area. It cannot be used on the frontend of the site.

There is another set of tests to identify pages on the frontend. [`is_home`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/), for instance, tests whether the current page is the homepage, while [`is_page('about-us')`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) will test whether you are on the About Us page. There is an [overview of these tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).